# Bus from Zabaikalsk to Manzhouli, ticket price

Tags: china, buses, russia, borders

I will take the train from Chita to Zabaikalsk. I arrive at 2:25 Moscow time. Then I would like to take the bus to Manzhouli and find a hostel/hotel in Manzhouli.

Do you know how much the bus ticket is?

Comment: Which train do you take from Chita, and on what day do you arrive there? It seems that there is a train from Zabaikalsk to Manzhouli each Friday and Sunday at 05:35 Moscow time, and it really looks like the same train as you take from Chita (i.e., it arrives to Zabaikalsk at 2:25 Moscow time)

Comment: I arrives on 28th of Nov. Yes, it should be the same train. But, it is very strange-------i cannot book the ticket to manzhouli online, although i can book it to zabaikalsk.

Comment: So i might stay on the strain, and pay some extra money to the conductor to go to manzhouli by the train?

Comment: Nov 28 is Saturday. Maybe the train on Saturdays goes only to Zabaikalsk, and only on Fridays and Sundays it continues to Manzhouli. I'll check.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. One day later there is a train, but no train to pass Zabaikalsk for Manzhouli on Nov 28. Though it seems that you can't buy tickets on that train online, you can only check the schedule.

Answer (score 1):

According to [information from 2012](http://www.0470.ru/show.asp?id=22&BigClassName=%D0%90%D0%92%D0%98%D0%90+%D0%98+%D0%96.%D0%94+%D0%91%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%AB&Smallclassname=), there are 10 buses per day. The cost is **400-450 roubles**, which was around **$15** during 2012.